# How can I export a Processing sketch as a video?

Tags: processing

I'm creating a 3D visualisation in Processing. I'm anticipating that each frame will take longer to draw than is acceptable for displaying the animation as a program, so I'd like to export it as a video.

Is this possible? What's the best way of going about it?

Comment: Professor Shiffman described the in-built method here, a mix of saveFrame() and the IDE-integrated tool for movie-making from sketches execution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2hI9XL6oyk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not using Processing 2.0 you can use MovieMaker library to export the sketch as a video (in processing 2.0 MovieMaker will be converted in a tool, but it doesn't work yet).

Other option is to use the saveFrame() method in your draw () function

[Here](http://www.supermanoeuvre.com/blog/?p=1067) you can find an example of how to use MovieMaker

and [here](http://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html) the docs of the saveFrame() method

Comment: `saveFrame()` is definitely the way to go.  You can pile those frames into Quicktime Pro < 7.6 if you have it, which has a nice Open Image Sequence feature and then Export to a quicktime, or you can try ffmpeg to stitch them together.  http://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: I had the same issue one month ago and I used the saveFrame() + Quicktime technique too

Comment: Yup, this worked well for me. `saveFrame()` combined with ffmpeg.

Comment: when using `saveFrame()` I am not getting all the frames, the result lags a lot. Anyone know what can I do?

Comment: @JordanBelf when using saveFrame() it's normal to have a low framerate (depending on the size of your sketch, but sometimes it can reach 1 fps or lower) but you should have all the frames exported

Comment: saveFrame() should not be used with millis() as a time function... instead do a fixed frame jump to avoid the lag. Writing to the hard drive takes longer than displaying to the screen.

Comment: I always use saveFrame() and delay(), just to make sure the animation is smooth

Comment: The first link, regarding MovieMaker, is broken.

Answer (score 7):

The [Video Export for Processing](http://funprogramming.org/VideoExport-for-Processing/) library allows direct mp4 export from Processing. It requires you to install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) on your system though.

Comment: Confirming this worked just perfectly with P3 + Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The GSVideo library [here](http://gsvideo.sourceforge.net/) helps with this in Processing 2.0. Has a class "GSMovieMaker" with objects much like described above.

Comment: It should be noted that GSVideo depends on gstreamer, which is common on many modern Linux distros but not on Windows or OS X.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of research I have written myself very simple code using ffmprg binaries:

```
if(frameCount<628){
    saveFrame("temp/anim_#####.png");
  }else if(frameCount == 628){
    println("Saving file!");
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("G:/.../ffmpg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", "-r", "60", "-i",
        "C:/.../temp/anim_%05d.png", "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-r", "30", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "C:/.../test.mp4");
    try {
      process = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Of course you need to adjust paths to files and ffmpeg binaries (https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). It sjould be Processing version independent, as it uses only saveFrame and calls external binaries to generate video. Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dear can use the Program made by Randel Shofer, you just have to modified 8,10 lines of code to use it with in your program ( and if you have more time you can do it without modifying the source code).

Program(Jar.) Link: http://www.randelshofer.ch/cubetwister/files/QuickTimeDemo2.jar

Description: http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2010/10/writing-quicktime-movies-in-pure-java/